# Java Application - Can i Store my sql queries in the DB rather than a file packaged inside the application?

Tags: java, sql, resources

As the application gets complicated, one thing that change a lot is the queries, especially if they are complex queries. Wouldn't it be easier to maintain the queries in the db rather then the resources location inside the package, so that it can be enhanced easily without a code change. What are the drawbacks of this?

Comment: Sure - stored procedures/functions are great for handling complex queries.  But somebody has to write/maintain/version control/deploy those procs/functions.

Comment: yeah, stored procedures can be versioned too, the key is complex queries. There are a lot of queries in your application that are very simple and select or updates a single column or row in a table. What i am curious about is why not maintain all your queries outside the application package, why maintain inside a application itself?

Comment: Using an ORM (like hibernate) removes the need to manually write any of the the simple CRUD queries.  For more interesting queries that live in the app, I want the text of the query to be in the same class that uses it.  For example, I don't want to jump between files to see the query parameter order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use stores procedures, to save your queries in the database. Than your Java code can just call the procedure from the database instead of building a complex query.
See wikipedia for a more detailed explanation about stored procedures:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure

You can find details about the implementation and usage in the documentation of your database system (MySql, MariaDb, Oracle...)

When you decide to move logic to the database, you should use a version control system for databases like liquibase: https://www.liquibase.org/get-started/quickstart
You can write the changes to you database code in xml, json or even yaml and check that in in your version control system (svn, git...). This way you have a history of the changes and can roll back to a previous version of your procedure, if something goes wrong.

You also asked, why some people use stored procedures and others keep their queries in the code.
Stored procedures can encapsulate the query and provide an interface to the data. They can be faster than queries. That is good.
But there are also problems

- you distribute the buisiness logic of your application to the database and the programm code. It can realy be troublesome, if the logic is spread through all technical layers of your applicaton.
- it is not so simple anymore to switch from a Oracle database to a MariaDb, if you use specific features of the database system. You have to migrate or rewrite the procedures.
- you have to integrate liquibase or another system into you build pipeline, to keep track of you database changes.

So it depends on the project and it's size, if either of the solutions is better.

Comment: I understand stored procedure is an option, invocation of a procedure is different that a query to run. What i am curious about is, what is a difference between maintain your queries in a file vs in db? Why aren't everyone using the db to maintain there queries?

Comment: guess versioning is the main reason there

Comment: I edited the answer to give a more detailed explanation about reasons for or against stored procedures

Comment: Here is also a discussion about good and evil stored procedures: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65742/stored-procedures-a-bad-practice-at-one-of-worlds-largest-it-software-consulting